# Create an object without calling a class

Tags: python, matlab

In matlab, I can create a structure array (struct) by doing the following.

```
person.name = 'Mike';
person.age = 25;
person.gender = 'male';
```

wherein person is not defined prior to creating the struct. When I try to do it in python, it gives me an error

```
name 'person' is not defined
```

Is there a similar way of doing it in python? Thanks

EDIT: Being new to python, I still think in matlab. The problem that I have is that I have a function that will take multiple inputs (more than 40), so instead of having function(input1,input2,...,input40), I will just have function(input) where the input consist of input.1, input.2,.., input.40.

Comment: Matlab's approach makes very little sense.  Why would you want to do something like that in Python?  What's wrong with doing things in Python following the Python language rules?  Why try to impose a different language's rules on Python?

Comment: Hi S.Lott, see my comment on kindall's response below.

Comment: You really want a python dictionary

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Python won't magically create a container object when you start assigning attributes to it, and if matlab allows this, I'd consider matlab badly broken.  Consider this:

```
person.name = "Mike"
persom.age  = 25
person.sex  = "Male"
```

Now we have two objects, `person` and `persom`, and `person` doesn't have `age`, *and there was no hint that this happened.* Later you try to print `person.age` and, one would hope, matlab then complains... two pages after the actual mistake.

A class can itself be used as a container or namespace. There's no need to instantiate it, and it'll save you a bit of typing if you just want a bundle of attributes.

```
class sex:
    male   = "M"
    female = "F"

class person:
    name = "Mike"
    age  = 25
    sex  = sex.male
```

To access or modify any of these, you can use `person.name`, etc.

N.B. I used a class for `sex` as well to illustrate one of the benefits of doing so: it provides consistency in data values (no remembering whether you used "M" or "Male" or "male") and catches typos (i.e. Python will complain about sex.mlae but not about the string "mlae" and if you were later checking it against "male" the latter would fail).

Of course, you still run the risk of misspelling `name`, `age`, or `sex` in this type of class definition. So what you can do is use the class as a template and instantiate it.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age=None, sex=None):
        self.name, self.age, self.sex = name, age, sex
```

Now when you do:

```
person = Person("Mike", 25, sex.male)
```

or if you want to document what all those parameters are:

```
person = Person("Mike", age=25, sex=sex.male)
```

it is pretty much impossible to end up with an object that has a misspelled attribute name. If you mess it up, Python will give you an error message at the point you made the mistake. That's just one reason to do it this way.

Comment: Your last suggestion is the best. With the 2nd last one, you can mess up the order e.g. `person = Person("Mike", sex.male, 25)`

Comment: Thanks kindall. Your explanation is clear and very useful. I agree that it's an error commonly encountered in matlab. If I may describe a bit why I asked the question. Being new to python, I still think in matlab. The problem that I have is that I have a function that will take multiple inputs (more than 40), so instead of having function(input1,input2,...,input40), I will just have function(input) where the input consist of input.1, input.2,.., input.40. My matlab-centric solution might not be possible in python and I might have to rethink the solution. Thanks

Comment: You could try adding each input to a list, and accessing each input value by the index of the list.  Order would matter, though, and it's not as a flexible solution as the ones above.

Comment: @mikeP:  You mean this?  `input={}; input['input1']=value; input['input2']=value; ...; function(**input)`?  If that's what you want in Python, please actually ask a question that includes **all** the details of what you're looking for.  Don't bury critical details in comments on an answer.  Please **update** the question to describe your actual use case.

Comment: @S.Lott: If you use ```function(**input)``` you don't need to instantiate a dict. just do function(a=1, b=2) will call your function with input = {"a":1, "b":2} because of the ** operator.

Answer (score 32):

In Python you can add members dynamically to an object, but (1) the name must already exist (it must have been assigned) and (2) it must be bound to an instance of some class. To do so you may create an empty class:

```
class Empty:
    pass        # empty statement otherwise the class declaration cannot succeed
```

construct an instance of it and assign it to your variable

```
person = Empty()
```

and then add whatever data you want

```
person.name = 'Mike'
person.age = 25
person.gender = 'male'
```

On the other hand, if you don't need the additional features a "normal" class provides and you just want to store some data in a key=>value fashion you should probably just use a dictionary.

```
person={}
person['name']='Mike'
person['age']=25
person['gender']='male'
```

(notice that, at least up to Python 2.7, this is mostly just a stylistic/syntactic difference, since instance members are implemented underneath in terms of dictionaries)

As a general guideline, you want classes when you are instantiating multiple objects made in the same way (and where typically the assignment to the members is done in the class constructor; adding members later generally makes for difficult to follow code), dictionaries otherwise.

Answer (score 18):

Python 3.3 Added [SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) class

> Unlike object, with SimpleNamespace you can add and remove attributes.
> If a SimpleNamespace object is initialized with keyword arguments,
> those are directly added to the underlying namespace.
>
> SimpleNamespace may be useful as a replacement for **class NS: pass**.
> However, for a structured record type use namedtuple() instead.

Here is an example on how you can use it:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

person = SimpleNamespace(name='Mike', age=25, gender='male')
print(person)
```

Output:

> namespace(age=25, gender='male', name='Mike')

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

person = SimpleNamespace()
person.name = 'Mike'
person.age = 25
person.gender = 'male'

print(person)
```

Output:

> namespace(age=25, gender='male', name='Mike')

Answer (score 16):

In Python, `person` has to be an instance of some class; it can't just materialize out of thin air.

You could achieve something similar to your code like so:

```
class Struct(object): pass

person = Struct()
person.name = 'Mike'
person.age = 25
person.gender = 'male'

print(person.__dict__)
```

This prints:

```
{'gender': 'male', 'age': 25, 'name': 'Mike'}
```

Comment: +1 for "can't just materialize out of _thin air_": My google search for "create Python instance out of thin air" took me right here!

Answer (score 7):

You probably want a dictionary (hash, associative array):

```
person = {'name': 'Mike', 'age': 25}
```

Answer (score 3):

While I would recommend NPE's or Matteo's as the preferred method, since functions are first class objects in python, they can also be used to emulate an empty class, but they cannot be instantiated as multiple objects (so you would only have one object instance per function).

```
>>> def person():pass
...
>>> person.name = 'Mike'
>>> person.name
'Mike'
>>> person
<function person at 0x020CF2F0>
```

It's weird, so I would not recommend using this, but it does illustrate that functions are first class objects in python.

Comment: Very nice example!